# Atom/Script package - how to move the output panel to the right and adjust the size?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

The Atom 'Script' package allows you to see the output of your code in a separate panel to your script. However by default it puts the panel horizontally, below the script panel.

[image]

I want the output panel to be displayed vertically, to the right of the script panel. I found out out to do this here: https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/pull/1516 by "adding `position: right` in the constructor's `super` method" in the lib/script-view.js file.

However, this side panel is very thin and there is no way to expand or contract it as there was when it was horizontal.

Why has this functionality disappeared, and how do I re-instate it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question for this because I wanted to use atom for python but since I had only been using python IDLE and editing in IDLE I have come to move the IDLE window to the left side of my screen and the program that I am working on on the right side.

I was finally able to locate the file that is responsible for creating the panel and determining its location.

To change the location of the panel you will have to navigate to the file location where the atom packages are located. For me it was within the path

C:\Users*nameOfUser*.atom\packages\script\node_modules\atom-message-panel\lib

in the folder there should be a JS file called "MessagePanelView". Open within your desired text editor. Once open you will see within "var MessagePanelView" there is

"this.position = params.position || 'bottom';"

once spotted you have the option of changing the text from 'bottom' to ['left','top','right'].

NOTE: when I had changed the positioning it worked almost as expected, the only problem was that the panel had auto adjusted and it ended up being too skinny. To fix this issue you can scroll down to "MessagePanelView.prototype.attach" and you should see "$(".panel-body", this).css" within this portion you will see that there is a value of "maxHeight" set, now all you have to do is add "width:" and the size that you would like.

I know that for the most part this solution is a temporary and clunky solution and that the panel is also not resizable is width. hopefully someone will be able to create a cleaner solution to the problem than I would be able to.

Comment: I did it exactly as you described, but it didn't work for me. Nothing changed (I restarted Atom).